# How to report odd sample sizes for the chi-squared test in a paper?

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size

I am testing a 2x2 set of data with chi-squared (expected values are all above 5, so I'm not using Fisher's exact test).

The there are two things being compared here. One has sample size 160, and one sample size 172. Data set:

```
GRASS,        TARMAC    
P,    G,      P,    G
172,  0,      106,  54
```

I'm comparing the values in grass and the values in tarmac. They have different sample sizes.

How do I present this when I am reporting it in my paper? N = what? Is it correct to write N = 172, 160?

Comment: What do you mean "the two sample sizes"?

Comment: @gung There are two data sets being compared, each having a different sample size.

Comment: How do you have two datasets? My reading of "a 2x2 set of data with chi-squared" suggests a single dataset. Can you paste your data into your Q?

Comment: @gung I don't think dataset is the word I'm looking for - oops. I've amended the original q - with the dataset.